# Problem specifying an objective function in optimization problem

Tags: python, matrix, optimization, compiler-errors, pulp

I have the following optimization problem written in Python

```
from pulp import LpProblem, LpVariable, lpSum, LpMaximize
# Person i in group j   
x = {(i, j): LpVariable(cat="Binary", name=f"x_{i}_{j}") for i in result_sum.index for j in result_sum.index}

# group j exists
y = {j: LpVariable(cat="Binary", name=f"y_{j}") for j in result_sum.index}

# objective function, maximize the punctuation of the people within each group
for i in result_sum.index:
    for j in result_sum.index:
        for k in result_sum.index:
            if i != j:
                prob += punctuation.loc[i, j] * x[i, k] * x[j, k]
# Each person belongs to one group
for i in result_sum.index:
    prob += lpSum(x[i, j] for j in result_sum.index) == 1

# Each group has between 2 and 3 members
for j in result_sum.index:
    prob += lpSum(x[i, j] for i in result_sum.index) >= 2 * y[j]
    prob += lpSum(x[i, j] for i in result_sum.index) <= 3 * y[j]

# Solve the problem
prob.solve()
```

If I run this code I get the error

```
line 91, in <module>
    prob += result_sum.loc[i, j] * x[i, k] * x[j, k]
    raise TypeError("Non-constant expressions cannot be multiplied")
TypeError: Non-constant expressions cannot be multiplied
```

Can someone please help me solve this problem?

Comment: It appears you are attempting to multiply 2 variables together...  that is non-linear and can't be done in `pulp`

Answer (score 0):

Without some example of what `result_sum` and `punctuation` look like I can't be sure if I understood your problem correctly.

Having said that, I'm guessing the `punctuation` dataframe contains the score of each individual for each group. In other words, it looks something like this:

|  | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 0 | 10 | 5 |
| B | 10 | 0 | 7 |
| C | 5 | 7 | 0 |
| D | 2 | 3 | 8 |
| E | 5 | 1 | 6 |
| F | 9 | 5 | 1 |

Where each index represents a different individual scores, and each column represents the score of that individual for some respective group.

If your goal is to maximize the punctuation of the people within each group, given that:

- Each individual can be assigned only to one group
- Each group must contain 2 or 3 individuals

Then, you could formulate the problem as follows:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pulp

# == Create some Example data ==================================================
# Assuming 'result_sum' just needs to have an index of individuals for this context
individuals = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']
result_sum = pd.DataFrame(index=individuals)

# Sample data for punctuation
# Assuming values represent the score of the individuals for each group
data = {
    '1': [0, 10, 5, 2, 5, 9],
    '2': [10, 0, 7, 3, 1, 5],
    '3': [5, 7, 0, 8, 6, 1],
}

punctuation = pd.DataFrame(data, index=individuals)
# ==============================================================================


# == Define and Solve the Optimization Problem ==================================
prob = pulp.LpProblem("max_score_per_group", sense=pulp.LpMaximize)

# Person i in group j
x = {(i, j): pulp.LpVariable(cat="Binary", name=f"x_{i}_{j}") for i in punctuation.index for j in punctuation.columns}

# Objective function: maximize the punctuation of the people within each group
obj = 0

for i in punctuation.index:
    for j in punctuation.columns:
        obj += punctuation.loc[i, j] * x[i, j]

prob.setObjective(obj)

# Each person can belong to only one group:
for i in punctuation.index:
    prob += pulp.lpSum(x[i, j] for j in punctuation.columns) == 1

# Each group must contain between 2 and 3 members
for j in punctuation.columns:
    prob += pulp.lpSum(x[i, j] for i in punctuation.index) >= 2
    prob += pulp.lpSum(x[i, j] for i in punctuation.index) <= 3

# Solve the problem
prob.solve()


# == Analyze Results ===========================================================
result = pd.DataFrame(
    np.zeros(punctuation.shape),
    index=punctuation.index,
    columns=punctuation.columns,
)

for i in punctuation.index:
    for j in punctuation.columns:
        result.loc[i, j] = x[i, j].value()

result = result.astype(int)

groups_score = (result * punctuation).sum(axis=0)
groups_score
# Returns:
#
# 1    19
# 2    17
# 3    14
# dtype: int64
```